# Python - MySQL SELECT query fetch specific data with dynamic table name

Tags: python, mysql, fetch

I am trying to fetch one some specific row from the MySQL DB in python.

hire my code

```
 table_name = students 
 ID = 1 
 query = ("SELECT name FROM %s where id=%s " %table_name)
try:
    cursor.execute(query, (ID))
    value = cursor.fetchall()
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

And I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: not enough arguments for format string

I have no idea, it because my format code or no.

Any help will be appreciate!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: you have 2 `%s`'s in your format string, but supply only one string to fill them with.

Comment: so what I suppose to do to fill 2 %s ? 
I try
 query = ("SELECT name FROM %s where id=%s " %table_name, id)

but it does't work too

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed in quotation marks.  If you have a tool that allows you write & test queries independent of Python, it would help separate problems w/ your SQL w/ problems in how you run queries from Python.